# Two rewrite rules in .htaccess

Tags: html, regex, .htaccess, web-applications

Currently I have the following code to remove .php from the url

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But I'd also like to replace the character _ in a filename with a / in the URL.
I've tried doing this but I simply get some weird errors.
Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: How many `_` chars can occur in the filename?

Comment: No more than one _ can occur.

Comment: Well, I have a file called blog_test-blog.php which will open correctly from the url /blog/test-blog however, images which are in the /images will not open correctly as there is no such directory as /blog/images, only /images

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated that only zero or one underscores may be part of a requested file, this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule .* - [S=2]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

To apply *both* rules (not just the first one) only if all three preceding conditions are true you negate the conditions and apply a skip rule afterwards: `[S=2]` means "skip the following 2 rules".

So if all of the new three conditions are false (and therefore their negation is true) the first rewrite appends `.php` to all requests. The second rewrite changes all underscores to slashes and stops rewriting.